# TextArea resize automatically based on content

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have a `<textarea>` as part of a form which users will input a list item. I decided to try using some jQuery to extend the height of the `<textarea>` upon the space was filled. I have got it to work in basic form, but I appear to have an issue, which is that every time the `keyup()` event is called, the height of the `<textarea>` increases, instead of when the content is filling it. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<textarea class="list_header_itemInput" placeholder="Enter an item..."></textarea>
```

My CSS:

```
.list_header_itemInput {
    width: calc(100% - 36px);
    line-height: 18px;
    resize: none;
    max-height: 180px;
}
```

And finally, my jQuery:

```
$('.list_header_itemInput').keyup(function() {
    $(this).css({ height: ($(this).height() + 2) });
});
```

What would I have to change in my code so that I get my intended result?

Comment: there are plugins that do this, review the source code for them. You won't do it in one or 2 lines of code

Comment: Sorry what means *`"upon the space was filled"`*? you mean you want to prevent scrollbars appear?

Comment: _“every time the keyup() event is called, the height of the <textarea> increases”_ – might that be due to the fact that that is _exactly what you’re doing_ in your code …?

Comment: Precisely what I wish for Roko

Comment: @CBroe - It does increase due to that, but I increase it to prevent the scrollbar appearing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the textarea's height to 1px, then measure the scrollHeight (the number of pixels represented by the scrollbar). Then set your textarea's height to (scrollHeight + 1).

```
$('.list_header_itemInput').keyup(function() { 
    this.style.height = "1px";
    this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight + 1) + "px";
});
```

Comment: Only tested in Chrome, but setting height to `0` and then not adding anything seems to work as well … Also in Chrome, I notice the scrollbar showing up for a split second when enter is pressed (and therefor the text jumping up and then down again once the height is adjusted). Tried to counter that here by adding a value to the height onkeydown for enter: http://jsfiddle.net/3r4gcgqg/ – although this feels kinda bad, because the `9` I add there is a “magic number” figured out by testing different values (and might differ for other browsers/other fonts/other line-height set for the textarea).

Answer (score 2):

perhaps you can use elastic js?: http://jsfiddle.net/janjarfalk/r3Ekw/
and insert this plugin into your html doc

```
<script src="http://jquery-elastic.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.elastic.source.js"></script>
```